# Umbraco - Load different content page which are at same level

Tags: umbraco7

I have an Umbraco site, where two content pages are at the same level and in the properties tab, the link do document in same (i.e. "/")... I always see only one of the content page is loaded.

Please let me know how to run the other content page (i.e Holden leasing home template) from browser.

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, all the root nodes are pointing to "/" ?
Is the "link to document" of Holden Leasing Home also "/" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click each of the home nodes and select "Culture and hostnames". Then you can set which URL(s) each node should respond to.

Like http://localhost:50234/interleasing , http://localhost:50234/mmsg and so forth.